# How to extract all ancestors of a nodes and leaves in a decision tree?

Tags: python, decision-tree, rules

I don't know how difficult is this question. Suppose we train a decision tree and then I want to records all nodes and leaves in the tree, what are their ancestors (set of p for parents), and which of their ancestors are divided based on x<a (set A_l) and x>a (set A_r).

Actually, nodes can be classified as follows and I want to extract all of this information:

```
t = 1,...,T   set of all nodes
p(t): parent of node t
A(t): set of all ancestors of node t
A_L(t): the set of ancestors of t whose left branch has been followed on the path from the root node to t
A_R(t): the set of ancestors of t whose left branch has been followed on the path from the root node to t
T_b: the set of branch nodes
T_l: the set of leaf nodes
```

I wrote a code and I could store all left and right children of a node, but I don't know how to determine the aforementioned sets.

```
class Nodes():
    no_nodes = 0
    def __init__(self,tree,no_total_nodes,node):
        self.no_nodes = no_total_nodes
        self.current_node= node
        self.left_child = all_left_children(tree,self.current_node)
        self.right_child = all_right_children(tree,self.current_node)
```

where

```
def func_right_node(tree,start_node):
    node = tree.children_right[start_node]
    return node

def func_left_node(tree,start_node):
    node = tree.children_left[start_node]
    return node


def all_right_children(tree,start_node):
    List=[]

    while True:

        r_node = func_right_node(tree,start_node)

        if r_node!= -1:
            List.append(r_node)
            start_node = r_node 
        elif r_node== -1:
            break
            
    return List

def all_left_children(tree,start_node):
    List=[]

    while True:

        r_node = func_left_node(tree,start_node)

        if r_node!= -1:
            List.append(r_node)
            start_node = r_node 
        elif r_node== -1:
            break
            
    return List
```

and all nodes and leaves are stores as follows:

```
TREE = decision_tree.tree_

total_number_nodes = decision_tree.tree_.node_count
All_Nodes = [] 
All_Leaves = []
for i in range(total_number_nodes):
    All_Nodes.append(Nodes(TREE,total_number_nodes,i))
    if not All_Nodes[i].left_child:
        All_Leaves.append(All_Nodes[i])
```

Comment: You start at a node or leaf and recursively get the parent node until reaching the root. If you want to traverse the whole tree, there are straightforward ways to do that using a similar approach.

Comment: It is possible to extract all rules by `export_text`, but I am confused how to convert it to the set of nodes of leaves, parents, left branched parents.

Comment: it's hard to answer this question without knowing what libraries you are using and some example code that shows what you've got so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: I found that from `sklearn.tree import export_text` provides the structure of the tree, but it is in form of if-then and it is like a text. Unfortunately, I am so novice in programming and Python and I am not familiar with recursive programming.